# How can I hide and unhide the project folder tree in sublime-text

Tags: sublimetext2, hotkeys

I can no longer see the project folder navigation tree on the left side of my interface.

I suspect I have hit some shortcut by accident that made it go away.

What are the shortuts to make the project folder navigation tree hide and unhide in sublime text?

Comment: Answer, for those arriving here from google.: Go to the menu "View -> Side Bar" and there is an entry for hiding and unhiding the sidebar. In my current key bindings it is Ctrl-K Ctrl-B which has to be typed one after the other. Currently I could not add this as an answer because the question is "closed".

Comment: On Ubuntu is `ctrl+k+b` GL [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38388062/5279996)

Answer (score 40):

By default:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+b"], "command": "toggle_side_bar" },
```

You can reach this settings at main menu: `Preferences -> Key Bindings - Default`.

and you can override as you like, at main menu: `Preferences -> Key Bindings - User`.

Comment: please advise to always show sidebar, not autohide. thanks

Answer (score 17):

By default if you are using mac os:

```
{ "keys": ["command+k", "command+b"], "command": "toggle_side_bar" }
```

Answer (score 12):

In **Command Panel** (`Ctrl+Shift+P`) type (or find) **View: Toggle Side Bar** and hit `Enter`

Answer (score 4):

I had something like that in my keymap.

```
{"keys": ["super+k", "super+b"], "command": "toggle_side_bar"},
```

In View -> Side Bar -> Show/Hide sidebar <kbd>⌘K</kbd>, <kbd>⌘B</kbd>. 
Which means "***Press and hold cmd then click buttons "b" and "k", then release cmd***".

I couldn't get that... I thought that there were two ways to toggle project tree (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> OR <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) but it's basically one command.

Answer (score 3):

To Toggle (hide or show) the side bar
press ctrl+K,ctrl+B (ctrl+K,B)

Comment: please advise to always show sidebar, not autohide. thanks

Answer (score 2):

**View / Side Bar / Show Sidebar <kbd>⌘K</kbd>, <kbd>⌘B</kbd>**